# Edit mesh icon not clickable

Tags: interface

i have used Blender 2.8 for quite a while now, and i got used to clicking the little green icon next to an object to switch into edit mode - now that i have downloaded Blender 3.0 it doesn't seem to work anymore - i'm sure i'm missing a simple thing here, but i can't figure it out.

Clicking this icon now doesn't seem to do anything, certainly it doesn't switch me into edit mode.
I know i can just press TAb, but i'm quite used to "my way" and it bothers me.

Would someone please enlighten me ?

Thank you very much for taking the time to read this and possibly help me.

Cheers

[image]

Comment: it didn't work in 2.9 either, so they must have dropped this option